# Spring WebFlux and WebClient Call not working

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor, spring-webclient

I'm a newbie in reactive programming, I have the following rest resource that calls a service that use WebClient to call an existing Rest API :

```
   @PostMapping
    public Mono<String> createUser(@RequestBody UserResourceDTO userResourceDto) {
        return userService.createUser(userResourceDto);
    }
```

in my service I have the following methode which works fine :

```
// Working method
   public Mono<String> createUser(UserResourceDTO userResourceDTO){
        return  httpCall(userResourceDTO);
  }
```

when I use this method the HTTP call is triggered and I see it in my log, but since I don't want to return the value from this method I tried the following method :

```
// Not Working method
    public Mono<String> createUser(UserResourceDTO userResourceDTO){
        Mono<String> rs = httpCall(userResourceDTO);
       return  Mono.just("just a value");
       
        // i plan to trigger another call to the DB this is why i don't want to return the result from httpCall
       // return userRepository.createUser(userResourceDTO);

}
```

this method is not working and the HTTP request is not triggered ( i don't see it in the console like the first method), can anyone explain to me why the second method is not triggering the WebClient call and why I'm obliged to return the result from `mhttpCall(userResourceDTO);`

this is httpCall code :

```
public Mono<String> httpCall(UserResourceDTO userResourceDTO) {

    WebClient webClient = WebClient.create();

    KeyCloakUser keyCloakUser = new KeyCloakUser();
    // setting values...
  
    return webClient.post()
            .uri(new URI("myurl"))
            .header("Authorization", "Bearer "+toremove)                
            .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
            .body(Mono.just(keyCloakUser), KeyCloakUser.class)
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(String.class);
}

// method with a second call not triggerd
public Mono<UserResourceDTO> twocalls(UserResourceDTO userResourceDTO){
     return httpCall(userResourceDTO)
        .flatMap(res -> {
        // Sysout not executed
        System.out.println(res);
        // my API return empty body with 201
        if("".equals(res)

          return userRepository.createUser(userResourceDTO)
        
        }
        );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of the common mistakes after switching to reactive programming. In reactive nothing happens until you subscribe. You need to chain async/sync functions using reactive operators like `flatMap`, `map`, etc.

Good starting point to understand the concept is [Flight of the Flux 1 - Assembly vs Subscription](https://spring.io/blog/2019/03/06/flight-of-the-flux-1-assembly-vs-subscription).

**Incorrect**

```
public Mono<String> createUser(UserResourceDTO userResourceDTO){
     Mono<String> rs = httpCall(userResourceDTO);
     return  Mono.just("just a value");
}
```

`httpCall(userResourceDTO)` will not be executed as a part of the reactive flow.

**Correct**

```
public Mono<String> createUser(UserResourceDTO userResourceDTO){
     return httpCall(userResourceDTO)
        .then(Mono.just("just a value"));
}
```

to continue with another async call

```
public Mono<String> createUser(UserResourceDTO userResourceDTO){
     return httpCall(userResourceDTO)
        .then(userRepository.createUser(userResourceDTO));
}
```

or, in case you need result of the HTTP call

```
public Mono<String> createUser(UserResourceDTO userResourceDTO){
     return httpCall(userResourceDTO)
        .flatMap(res -> userRepository.createUser(userResourceDTO));
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for the Clair and clean explanation

Comment: i tried your last suggestion but it doesn't work i want to test the result fro http call before trigger the second call but its not working even the sysout inside flatmap is not working this is the method public Mono<String> createUser(UserResourceDTO userResourceDTO){
     return httpCall(userResourceDTO)
        .flatMap(res -> {
  
  System.out.println(res)
  // my API return empty body with 201
  if("".equals(res)

    return userRepository.createUser(userResourceDTO)
  
  }
  );
}

Comment: please share more details about "it doesn't work" and how do you tests. Also what is returned from httpCall? It would be useful if you update original questions with more details

Comment: i updated my question by adding the method with problem "twocalls()"  and "it doesn't work" which means the second call inside flatMap is not executed. thanks in advance

Comment: are you sure "" is returned? it could be that it returns `Mono.empty()` and in this case `flatMap` will not get any signal. you can decorate it with `log` to understand what signals are sending `httpCall(userResourceDTO).log()`

Comment: httpCall(userResourceDTO).log().then(Mono.just("just a value"));  in the log there is the text ""just a value"" but i want to get the response body form httpCall to test if there is no error then i trigger the second call to create the user in the DB only if the httpCall is ok

Comment: Do you see complete signal in log? In case `httpCall` returns `Mono.empty()` (complete signal) `flatMap` will not be resolved and you need to use `then` that just raining reactive functions but return value from the previous step is not available.